# android: tableLayout is not shown

Tags: android

i have a tableLayout that is created via xml and filled in code.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

My activity has these member variables:

```
TableLayout tableLayout;
String[] items = new String[] {"text1", "text2"};
TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams;
TableLayout.LayoutParams params;
```

this is what happens in the onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
        //...
    }
```

i fill the tableLayout with this method

```
void createRow(int id, String s) {
   TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
   row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
   Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
   spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   spinner.setSelection(id);
   row.addView(spinner);
   EditText editText = new EditText(this);
   editText.setText(s);
   editText.setLayoutParams(params);
   editText.setEms(15);
   row.addView(editText);
   Button button = new Button(this);
   button.setLayoutParams(params);
   button.setText("+");
   button.setOnClickListener(Add);
   row.addView(button);
   button = new Button(this);
   button.setLayoutParams(params);
   button.setText("X");
   button.setOnClickListener(Remove);
   button.setTag(tableLayout.getChildCount());
   row.addView(button);

   tableLayout.addView(row);
}
```

naturally `Add` and `Remove` are `onClicklistener`. The Method is called with `0` and `""`, but my activity is still empty. Can anyone tell me, why?
The TableLayout is drawn, but seems to have no height(i experimented with setting a background color and changing the height in the xml)

Comment: I think you have to set the layoutParams to the row after creating it, before adding it to layout.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: but you have to use TableLayout.LayoutParams,  from your posted code you are using the wrong params. Because the rows are inside your TableLayout, you need to use the TableLayout params...

Comment: also no effect. btw a TableLayout is a LinearLayout

Comment: **TableLayout is a LinearLayout**....doesn´t matter, if You are using `TableLayout` as a parent, you have to use this params. Even the params for the `Spinner`, because the spinner is inside a row, you have to use `TableRow.LayoutParams`.  I see your params have height and width WRAP_CONTENT...if for example none of your views got some content to show, everything will be "invisible".....

Comment: as i said i tried it and it had no effect, and the buttons should have content

Comment: yes sure, you said you tried it, BUT have you tried it with the TableLayout and TableRow.LayoutParams? This you haven´t specified....and also, HOW do you have tried. It´s important, in Development you can stumple about every little detail.....

Comment: edited my post with the changes